# arma::vector mistaken with std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, armadillo, overloading

The C++11 features of [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) are disabled on Cygwin. But it works on Linux.

I want my code to be cross platform.

At first:

```
// constructor
MyClass(arma::vec x)
{
    init(x);
}
```

And when I passed an array to it, it didnt work because C++11 options of Armadillo is not enabled on Cygwin:

```
MyClass a({1.0,2.0,3.0});
```

It will result into error in Cygwin while works in Linux.

To fix this problem, I modified the code by adding another constructor:

```
// constructor
MyClass(arma::vec x)
{
    init(x);
}

// constructor
MyClass(std::vector<double> x)
{
    arma::vec x2;
    for(auto d:x)
        x2<d;
    init(x2);
}
```

Now, this code works on Cygwin fine but in Linux it leads to error.

```
MyClass a({1.0,2.0,3.0});

error: call of overloaded ...  is ambiguous
```

How to fix this ambiguity?

Comment: `init(x)` Please stop using 2-stage initializing. That's what C++11 delegating constructors are for. Also, wouldn't it be easier to just *fix* the Armadillo issue on Cygwin?

Comment: @NicolBolas, Armadillo is a library out of my hand. The C++11 is not the issue of Armadillo, but it is issue of Cygwin to implement it incomplete. Btw, how to avoid `init` in this case? I cannot call another constructor before I create `x2`.

Comment: I don't know the details of Armadillo's `vec` class, but something like this: `MyClass(const std::vector<double> &x): MyClass(arma::vec(x.begin(), x.end()))`. Or whatever other interface their vector class provides. Also, I'd suggest taking the `std::vector` parameter by `const&` instead of value, since you're not going to move from it.

Comment: @NicolBolas, here using begin and end does not work `no matching function for call to ‘arma::Col<double>::Col(std::vector<double>::iterator, std::vector<double>::iterator)’
  : MyClass(arma::vec(x.begin(), x.end()))` . Thanks for `const &`, I will apply that in my codes.

Comment: I didn't expect it to work. Like I said: "Or whatever other interface their vector class provides." That means "Go look at their documentation and find an appropriate constructor for copying arrays of data".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create ctor that accepts `std::initializer_list<double>`

Comment: Works like charm. But how does it differ from `std::vector<double>`  ?

Comment: Constructors with initializer_list are strongly preferred when you pass braced initializer